# How to group sum along timestamp in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

one years' data showed as follows:

```
datetime                 data
2008-01-01 00:00:00      0.044
2008-01-01 00:30:00      0.031
2008-01-01 01:00:00      -0.25
    .....
2008-01-31 23:00:00      0.036
2008-01-31 23:30:00      0.42
2008-01-02 00:00:00      0.078
2008-01-02 00:30:00      0.008
2008-01-02 01:00:00      0.09
2008-01-02 01:30:00      0.054
    .....
2008-12-31 22:00:00      0.55
2008-12-31 22:30:00      0.05
2008-12-31 23:00:00      0.08
2008-12-31 23:30:00      0.033
```

There is a value per half-hour. I want the sum of all values in a day, so convert to 365 rows values.

```
year     day   sum values
2008     1         *    
2008     2         *
 ...
2008     364       *
2008     365       *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) + [`dt.dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby([df['datetime'].dt.year, df['datetime'].dt.dayofyear]).sum()
print (df)
                    data
datetime datetime       
2008     1        -0.175
         2         0.230
         31        0.456
         366       0.713
```

And if need `DataFrame` is possible convert index to column and set columns names by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df['datetime'].dt.year, df['datetime'].dt.dayofyear])['data']
       .sum()
       .rename_axis(('year','dayofyear'))
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   year  dayofyear   data
0  2008          1 -0.175
1  2008          2  0.230
2  2008         31  0.456
3  2008        366  0.713
```

Comment: 'dayofyear' ,amazing!